# How to ignore spaces in file path for bash select statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames

I have the following Bash Script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/;

files=$(find . -name iaGambro_gambro.sql)

select file in $files; do
    if [ -n "$files" ]; then
        sudo sqlite3 -header -column "${file}"
    fi
    break
done
```

It should return the following 2 results:

```
1) ./2EFF5EBF2B2D/Library/Private Documents/iaGambro_gambro.sql
2) ./A1AF3463BFD2/Library/Private Documents/iaGambro_gambro.sql
```

But it is is returning the following 4 because of the white space in `Private Documents`:

```
1) ./2EFF5EBF2B2D/Library/Private 
2) Documents/iaGambro_gambro.sql
3) ./A1AF3463BFD2/Library/Private 
4) Documents/iaGambro_gambro.sql
```

How do I get the select to recognize the paths with the spaces?

**NOTE:** I'm looking for how to execute on the given path, not just print it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find ... -exec` option:

```
find . -name iaGambro_gambro.sql -exec bash -c '
  select file do
    : Do something with "$file"
    break
  done
' bash {} +
```

Comment: am I right to assume `: Do something with "$file"` is sudo code?

Comment: @SethMcClaine: Yes, whatever you want to do with `"$file"`

Comment: ok, I think thats what I'm looking for, confirming now